# Diameter of Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

"The diameter of a tree (sometimes called the width) is the number of nodes on the longest path between any two nodes in the tree".

Will the C++ function below works for all cases to find the diameter of a binary tree? Called as `s=0`, and `root` = root of the binary tree

```
int helper(node *root,int &s){

  int l = 0, r = 0;

  if(root == NULL){
     return 0; 
  }
  l= helper(root->left,s);  //height of left subtree.
  r= helper(root->right,s); //height of right subtree.

  int mx_single=max(l,r)+1;
  int mx_top=max(mx_single,l+r+1);
  s=max(s,mx_top);
  return mx_single;
}
```

After returning to main, `ans` will be `s`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks wrong to me for many cases, but it would be helpful if your variable names were more descriptive.  The function needs to return the diameter of the specified tree, but the recursive implementation also needs to use the height of each sub-tree.

Taking your definition of diameter to include the leaf nodes in the count, it can be reformulated recursively like so:

- if the tree consists of a single node, then its diameter is 1.  (The whole tree is a single-node path from one leaf node to itself).
- if the root node of the sub-tree has exactly one child then its diameter is the diameter of the sub-tree rooted at that child.  That follows because all the leaf nodes are in the subtree, therefore all the acyclic paths from leaf to leaf are confined to the subtree.
- otherwise, the diameter is the greatest among the diameter of the left subtree, the diameter of the right subtree, and one plus the sum of the heights of the two subtrees (measured in nodes).  This considers the possibilities that the longest leaf-to-leaf path is contained in the left subtree, is contained in the right subtree, or passes through the root.  In the last case you don't need to identify the actual path; the subtree heights tell you how long it is (+ 1 node for the root).

Receiving the sub-tree heights to handle the third alternative appears to be the purpose of parameter `s` in your program, but you don't ever *use* it.

Your program will return the wrong result for a wide variety of trees, among them

```
  N
 /
1
```

(diameter 1, but your function will return 2)

```
  2
 / \
1   3
```

(diameter 3, but your function will return 2)

```
  3
 / \
2   4
 \
  1
```

(diameter 4, but your function will return 3)

```
  N
 / \
N   4
   / \
  3   5
 /   /
2   6
 \   \
  1   7
```

(diameter 7, but your function will return 5)

[In each figure, nodes along a path that measures the tree diameter are numbered, and all other nodes are designated 'N'.]

In fact, your function returns the *height*, counted in nodes, not the diameter.  It looks like under favorable circumstances it may record the diameter in `s`, but not consistently.

Comment: If the height of a 1-node tree is 0, then I think the third term in that max expression should use the constant 2 instead of 1 -- at least, using the *usual* meaning of "diameter" that refers to edges.  With the "number of nodes ... between" definition given by the OP, it's not clear if only internal nodes should be counted (in which case 1 is correct) or all nodes (in which case it should be 3).

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I have clarified the assumptions and definitions as used in the formula.  For what it's worth, I prefer to count tree height by nodes rather than by edges, for that yields different heights for zero-node and one-node trees.  That's also a more convenient definition for the purposes of this problem, and it's consistent with the given definition of diameter.

Comment: @ John Bollinger can you please provide me a test case for which the above method fails? okk you can give it in the level order manner with values of nodes , if there is no child then simply put it as  -1.

Comment: @sb15, I have revised my answer with a more complete explanation and examples.

Comment: @ John Bollinger  First of all I am never getting diameter directly from the return value of the function. It is only stored at s after it returns back to the main function , so according to that in all the cases (except 1st one) I'm getting the absolutely correct value in s as diameter( again I repeat it's not the value returned by the function). So for the 1st one and similar skew cases I updated the definition of diameter. So would you think of any other case where it fails?

Comment: @sb15, it is extremely counter-intuitive that a function to compute the diameter and named "diameter" does not *return* the diameter.  With that said, it does appear that a top-level call to your revised function will reliably result in `s` being set to the tree diameter, provided that `s` is initially `0`.

Comment: @ John Bollinger Ok sorry for that, I have changed the function name :). Is it ok now, any bugs further?  please review it once more and tell  me.