# Diameter of a Binary Tree

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, tree-traversal, postorder

I am working on a famous problem called the Diameter of a Binary Tree. I know this has been discussed numerous times ([Diameter of Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957990/diameter-of-binary-tree)) here but the explaination doesn't seem correct. In particular, a single node tree should return 0, not 1 (I checked from Leetcode's own checker). Anyway, here is the problem statement:

> Given a binary tree, you need to compute the length of the diameter of the tree. The diameter of a binary tree is the length of the longest path between any two nodes in a tree. This path may or may not pass through the root.

[image]

Answers are 0, 1, and 5, respectively. From the first glance, it seems calculating the number of edges of the left subtree and the number of right subtree should yield the answer.

So I started with postorder recursion (bottom up):

```
max_diameter = 0
def getDiameter(node):
    if node is NULL:
        return 0 

    left_diameter = getDiameter(node.left)
    right_diameter = getDiameter(node.right)

    max_diameter = max(left + right, max_diameter)
```

So far so good. But the code doesn't work, and I am struggled to understand some of the solutions out there. For example:

```
class Solution(object):
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        self.ans = 0

        def depth(p):
            if not p: return 0
            left, right = depth(p.left), depth(p.right)
            self.ans = max(self.ans, left+right)
            return 1 + max(left, right)

        depth(root)
        return self.ans
```

Why compare the left subtree and the right subtree? Why + 1? Also, some say find the height, some say find the depth. This is confusing and I feel folks are just throwing terms out there... Any clarification is helpful.

Comment: The more widely accepted definition is that it's the _number of nodes on the longest path_ in the tree _between two leaves_; this path may or may not go through the root. I don't know how to define the diameter of a tree that doesn't have at least two leaves; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66827790/839733.

Answer (score 0):

The longest path always goes from a leaf up to a node and then back down to a different leaf. Seen from the node, this path has the length as the sum of the maximum depth of the left subtree and the maximum depth of the right subtree.

We cannot just apply this to the root node, as your third example shows the node might be anywhere in the tree. So you have to test all the nodes and get the maximum solution:

```
diameter (Leaf)     = 0
diameter (Node l r) = max(diameter l, diameter r, depth l + depth r)

depth (Leaf)     = 0
depth (Node l r) = 1 + max(depth l, depth r)
```

The solution you found recursively computes the depths on all nodes, and along the way also updates the maximum diameter in the `self.ans` slot.

Answer (score 0):

At each node, you need to know depth of your children to calculate the diameter of tree from that, where diameter is basically how far can you go from your deepest node in your left child till your deepest node in right child.

In reference to to your second code (solution to this problem), we are calculating depth from each node, meanwhile keeping track of longest path we have seen so far at each of the explored nodes.
Here is a bit more commented style of it:

```
def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root):

    self.longest = 0

    def depth(node):

        if not node:
            return 0

        left_depth = depth(node.left)
        right_depth = depth(node.right)

        # A path is longest if we add depths from both sides
        # Overall Longest is maximum of what we have seen so far and this path
        self.longest = max(self.longest, left_depth+right_depth)

        # Depth at this node is maximum of either of our children +1 (our own node)
        return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1

    # Calculating depth, meanwhile tracking the longest path in self.longest
    depth(root)

    return self.longest
```