# What is the diameter of a tree that doesn't have at least two leaves?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

> The diameter of a tree T is the largest of the following quantities:
>
> 1. the diameter of T's left subtree
> 2. the diameter of T's right subtree
> 3. the longest path between leaves that goes through the root of T (this can
>    be computed from the heights of the subtrees of T)

Source: https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring00/cps100/assign/trees/diameter.html

However, it doesn't say what is the diameter of tree that doesn't have at least two leaves, like a root-only tree, or 1 -> 2? Is it 0, undefined, infinity or negative infinity?

Comment: From what I know, it should be 0 for a root only tree and 1 for 1->2

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Can you cite a source? What you're saying can't be derived from the definition I posted.

Comment: I don't have a formal source, just using the 3rd point of the definition

Comment: A longest simple path (can be assumed for trees that it is simple paths) is a number between 0 and n-1 given a tree or graph with n nodes.  So based on the description you give, a tree with one or two nodes clearly has a longest path between leaves of 0.  A source is not necessary, its right in the definition as mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

A better definition of diameter is simply "the length of the longest path". The root only tree has diameter 0, and the path on two vertices has diameter 1. The rules given are "unnecessarily" complicated, but that's because they also give a way to *calculate* the diameter. Also, note that, in a graph theoretic sense, if the root is missing all or all but one of its children, it *is* a leaf itself, and so you can see the third clause as actually covering the problem cases.

Comment: Root missing one child is not a leaf by any definition.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar [Except it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#:~:text=leaf). In graph theory, which is where the idea of diameter comes from, trees are not structured with a "privileged" root. Any node with only one link to the rest of the tree is a leaf. It's a little different from the convention in computer science because the way we use trees is different.

Comment: I see "_A leaf is a vertex with no children_" that doesn't corroborate with your claim and neither does "_a tree with only a single vertex (hence both a root and leaf) has depth and height zero_". A root missing one child still has another subtree, and hence is not a leaf by either of the above definition. If there's something else on that page, please quote instead of posting a general link.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I set the link to autoscroll to the relevant sentence, but maybe your browser doesn't support that. I'll just quote it "Similarly, an external vertex (or outer vertex, terminal vertex or leaf) is a vertex of degree 1." That definition should also include vertices of degree 0, but that's a special case applying to only one tree. Also, you're kinda missing the point. The definition in the question is bad, you can make it work by stretching the meaning of "leaf" from the CS version to the graph theory version, and the fundamental thing is "diameter = length of the longest path".

Comment: I see that statement now, but given the contradictory statements made on that page, I'm not totally convinced. As you pointed out, they conveniently omitted the case of a single-node tree, and "_A leaf is a vertex with no children"_ contradicts "_external vertex (or outer vertex, terminal vertex or leaf) is a vertex of degree 1_". I upvoted you for trying, and am going to look into some textbook now.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar if the root has only one child, it can also be considered a leaf if the edges are undirected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the definition given, it would have to be 0 for both the case where there is one node or two nodes in the tree.  A path has a length of 0 to n-1 for an n node tree.  A diameter of infinity or negative infinite as well as undefined make no logical sense, and the 3rd definition always gives a numeric answer.  Perhaps a better definition is needed, yet it really is task dependent as to why one would define diameter in the first place.  Obviously this is a recursive definition so it would need a base case anyway.  The left or right subtree would eventually be a 1 or 2 node tree.  But logically the definition as it is constructed there seems imprecise and not particularly useful except for properly balanced binary trees with an odd number of nodes and whose nodes only contain two leaves.

Diameter for generalized binary trees or trees even in general would require a better definition.  The easiest way to fix this for generalized binary trees is to define the path length to be between the two leaves or if there are not two leaves, then from the root to its leave e.g. 1.  Otherwise the recursive construction breaks.  Likewise general trees could simply make it the largest of the diameters for all the children rather than just the left and right one.